# Ipad Viewport Dimesnions

Tags: css, ipad, ios-simulator

In pixels, what are the dimensions of the iPad in both portrait and landscape mode (when the address bar is visible)?

I have had a good look around on the internet and, surprisingly, cannot find an answer.
Most resources list the device dimensions and not the view port dimensions.

If I use iOS Simulator, take a screen shot and open it in Photoshop the height in Portrait mode is 930px. However, if I create a page and view it in the simulator I can make the page as tall as 1163px before it is cut-off which doesn't seem right!

If anyone can provide the dimensions, I would be most grateful.

Comment: The iPad scales pages to fit the width, do you have a `viewport` meta tag in your markup?

Comment: Oh yeah - The view port was missing! After I added I found out that the dimensions are as follows: Portrait w - 759px h - 910px  Landscape w - 1015px h - 660px. I hope that helps someone!